# How to run javascript from c# in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I am new to Asp.Net and i have my aspx page like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestJs.aspx.cs" Inherits="tms.Test.TestJs" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="StyleSection" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentSection" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel">
            <asp:Button ID="btnAlert" OnClick="btnAlert_OnClick" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptSection" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc() {
            $.alert("Hello Mz");
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

And my .cs file looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace tms.Test
{
    public partial class TestJs : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnAlert_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "newFunc", "myFunc()", true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button the script does not call up and give some object expected error.

I am really stuck at this. Please help me. 
Thanx In Advance.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587817/how-to-write-javascript-coding-in-c-sharp-code-behind

Comment: Try this `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "newFunc", "myFunc()", false);` Make last argumanet `false`.

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Yes let me check it and get back to you.

Comment: @MairajAhmad: It worked but it doesn't show alert. "myFunc()" gets printed on top of my page.

Comment: Replace `$.alert("Hello Mz");` with `alert("Hello Mz")`;

Comment: var script = String.Format(@"alert('Hello Mz');");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "mzFunc", script, true);   -    I tried this and it worked

Answer (score 3):

In the button click event scriptmanager can be called

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Your Comment","myFunc();", true);}
```

Change your script like below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc() {
        alert("Hello Mz");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: May i ask where do i put this code. On the button click event or Page_Load event.

Comment: It should work perfectly. You have to put the code in your button click event, not page load.

Comment: Replace $.alert("Hello Mz"); with alert("Hello Mz");

Comment: var script = String.Format(@"alert('Hello Mz');"); ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "mzFunc", script, true); - I tried this and it worked

Comment: are you sure your myFunc() is rendering in the page? Because it is under different content place holder. Try to put your <script></script> block inside ContentSection place holder.

Comment: Can you ensure that in master page "ScriptSection" is below the "ContentSection". I am just guessing if somehow that javascript function is not properly loaded. Also just for checking keep both button section and javascript in the same contentplaceholder and check if it works

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't understand why you are using the `ScriptManager` here.
An ASP Button has a property named `onClientClick`. See this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

You can change your button's code in the HTML like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAlert" OnClick="btnAlert_OnClick" onClientClick="myFunc();" runat="server"/>
```

**Note: The `onClientClick` will be executed before the `onClick` event.
This is written out of my head and untested!**

Comment: Yes you are right. But actually i want to do some C# code behind and then i want to call js. But it wasnt working so i created a testpage like this and asked you to guide me.